# UITabController Child UIViewControllers Do Not Resize

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, resize, uitabbarcontroller, swift

UITabViewControllers containing a single label do not resize properly in a UITabBarController. I can replicate this with the following steps;

1. New single view application, set the Main storyboard to `wAny hRegular`
2. Add `Tab Bar Controller` from Object library
3. Move initial view pointer from default `View Controller` to the new `Tab Bar Controller`
4. Delete the default `View Controller`
5. Add a label to each `View Controller` that are connected to the `Tab Bar Controller`, making sure to anchor the label to the centre of the `View Controller`

The result should look like the following;
[image: Main Storyboard]

Now when I run the application on my device or in the simulator the label is not central;
[image: Running Application]

My question is: why don't the `View Controllers` resize to fit in the `Tab Controller`?
What do I need to do to make them automatically inherit the parent view frame?

I've tried setting the `autoresizeSubviews` and `autoresizingMask` in various places but I'm just guessing at this point. I was hoping to set this behaviour in the storyboard but if not, code is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "making sure to anchor the label to the centre"? How did you do that.

Comment: You have shown that the label is not where you expected but not necessarily that the view controller's view's frame is not where you expected. In addition what autolayout (or autoresizing) settings have you defined for those labels? Without knowing what rules you set for their positioning it is not possible to comment on why they are not positioned where you intended.

Comment: This might be a case of my lack of understanding of the layout system on iOS (I came from XAML and .NET). I guess my question is; how can I ensure the frame of the UIViewController is resizing to fill the gap left on screen between the status bar and Tab Bar Controller?